# Sound problem with Chrome

Tags: 13.04, sound, google-chrome

Ubuntu 13.04 Installed, worked but few days ago sound disappeared on youtube, so now there is no sound in Google Chrome, but it works in VLC and Rythmbox.

Comment: Have you tried Chromium?

Answer (score 1):

There's likely a problem with the Flash plugin.

- Try Firefox. Do YouTube videos have sound in Firefox?
- Visit chrome://plugins/ in Google Chrome. Do you have multiple **Adobe Flash Player** plugins? Try disabling one or the other.
- Try YouTube [HTML5 video](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

My flash player works. Here are my chrome flash plugin settings:

[image: my chrome flash plugin settings]